# Override mutator's value in eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Given following code:

```
class Picture {

    public function getAbsolutePathAttribute() {
        return "absolute_path"
    }
}

$picture = new Picture();
echo $picture->absolute_path; // prints "absolute_path"

$picture->absolute_path = "I will override you no matter what";
echo $picture->absolute_path; // prints "absolute_path"
```

Is there way of overriding an eloquent mutator attribute?

I have tried a magic method:

```
setAbsolutePathAttribute($value) {
    $this["attributes"] = $value;
}
```

However it did not work.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why does `getAbsolutePathAttribute()` return a fixed value?

Comment: The first one is called an `Accessor`. The latter `setAbsolutePathAttribute` is the Mutator. If you make your Accesor to return a **fixed** value I guess there is not much hope for you to try to get a different thing later.

Answer (score 2):

So I don't recommend trying to solve this by overriding the mutator. You might be able to, but the less you touch the core of Laravel the better. Why? Because you never know what future Laravel code could look like.

A core change could possibly break your internal override the next time you do a minor or major Laravel version upgrade.

So, 2 ways to solve this, given your simple example:

*1. Create a default value at the database level*

Laravel migrations feature a default column modifier, it looks something like this: `->default('something')`

That way you don't need the mutator at all for getting that default value you're looking for.

You can read more about them here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#column-modifiers

*2. Make your accessor smarter*

Your example is pretty simple, so I'll just work with it:

```
class Picture {

    public function getAbsolutePathAttribute() {
        if(is_null($this->absolute_path)) {
             return "absolute_path";
        }

        return $this->absolute_path;
     }
}
```

That way it only does something if there is no value present.

Comment: thanks for answer, i sort of thought that is not possible

Comment: I believe option 2 should be "Make your *accessor* smarter"